# Send a Message between users

Tags: django, message

I want to send messages between two users but I've two issues:
First, the text area contains the message form and it shows the HTML code, and I want to hide the HTML code, for keep text area clean.
Second, it throws an exception with the name of the message body field.
Here's my code:

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/sn/login/')
def compose(request, email):
    send_from = UserProfile.objects.get_profile_user(request.user.email)
    send_to = UserProfile.objects.get_profile_user(email)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(send_from, sent_to, None, None)
            ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('inbox'))
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
    return render_to_response('sn/messages/compose.html',
            {'form': form, 'user': send_to},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label="Introduce tu mensaje", max_length=500)

    def clean(self):
        body = self.cleaned_data['body'] # Error is in this line
        if len(body) > 0:
            raise ValidationError('No puedes enviar un mensaje vacio')
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, send_from, send_to, parent_msg, replied_at):
        body = self.cleaned_data['body'] 
        message = Message(send_from = send_from,
                          send_to = send_to,
                          body = body,
                          parent_msg = parent_msg)
        message.save()
        if replied_at is not None:
            message.replied_at = replied_at
            message.save()
        return message
```

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    send_from = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='sent_messages')
    send_to = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='received_messages', null=True, blank=True)
    parent_msg = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next_messages', null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    replied_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

compose.html

```
{% load i18n %} 

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
<h5>Escribe aqu&iacute; tu mensaje</h5>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</textarea><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/><br/>
<a href="{% url 'messages_inbox' %}">Cancelar</a><br/>
</form>
```

The error is:
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'body'

Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the error after submitting the form? Could you post the full stacktrace (and check the value of request.POST)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</textarea>
```

`form.as_p` renders your form as html, so you're rendering HTML inside a `textarea`block.

compose.html should look something like this:

```
{% load i18n %} 

<h5>Escribe aqu&iacute; tu mensaje</h5>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
    {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/><br/>
   <a href="{% url 'messages_inbox' %}">Cancelar</a><br/>
</form>
```

If you want the form to display a textarea, you can set that in your MessageForm class:

```
class MessageForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label="Introduce tu mensaje", max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score -1):

`cleaned_data` in form is populated after running `clean` method, so you can't acces data from it inside `clean`. What you can do is use `clean_body` method or call:

```
cleaned_data = super(MessageForm, self).clean()
```

and use that returned `cleaned_data` instead. Also you must remember to return that `cleaned_data` in your clean method if everything is okay.